# How can I redirect %26 in URLs to %2526 using a .htaccess rule?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, drupal

I would like `.htaccess` to redirect:

```
example.com/something_%26_else
```

to

```
example.com/something_%2526_else
```

I'm importing a bunch of pages that have ampersands in the title from MediaWiki. These are encoded as `%26`. Drupal, for various reasons, has decided double encode the URL to have it become `%2526`. I simply can't create the alias within Drupal so I have to use `.htaccess`.

This is what I have as my rule so far:

```
RewriteRule ^w/([^%26]+)\%26(.*)$ w/$1\%2526$2 [R=301]
```

I asked this question three months ago on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000846/replace-26-in-htaccess-to-2526) and was not able to get it working. I tried hiring a contractor for this but was unable to find one. So this is my last ditch effort before I completely give up. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: In all honesty, wouldn't it be better for everyone involved to run an UPDATE query against drupal's database to convert all the %26's back to ampersands, so that Drupal stops double-encoding them?

Comment: @DerfK That would break links from other sites. Since there's about a 1000 pages with this problem, I would like to avoid this but if I don't find a solution, then that I just have to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 'noescape|NE' (no URI escaping of
>   output)
>
> This flag prevents mod_rewrite from
>   applying the usual URI escaping rules
>   to the result of a rewrite.
>   Ordinarily, special characters (such
>   as '%', '$', ';', and so on) will be
>   escaped into their hexcode equivalents
>   ('%25', '%24', and '%3B',
>   respectively); this flag prevents this
>   from happening. This allows percent
>   symbols to appear in the output

[mod_rewrite Documentation at Apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer (on Drupal.SE) to the question "[How to use the Rules module to implement a custom redirect for an outdated URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170742/how-to-use-the-rules-module-to-implement-a-custom-redirect-for-an-outdated-url)". I bet the solution described there (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) also works for this case.

As detailed in that answer: the "clue" to get this to work, is to use the Rules Event "Drupal is initializing". That will ensure that the rule gets triggered BEFORE the actual content is shown.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, `%26` is a URL-encoded (aka "%-encoded") `&` (ampersand).

To redirect a *request* for `/something%26else` literally (or `/something&else`, since the ampersand does not *need* to be escaped in the URL-path) to `/something%2526else` (ie. `/something%26else` when decoded) then you could do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(something)&(else)$ /$1\%26$2 [R,L]
```

Or, the more generic `/<anything>%26<anything>`:

```
RewriteRule (.*)&(.*) /$1\%26$2 [R,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path (ie. `&`, not `%26`). So you should simply specify `&` (ampersand) literally. Note that this will match a request for both `/something_%26_else` and `/something_&_else`.

The `%` (percent) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* needs to be backslash escaped in order to represent a literal `%`, otherwise it's going to be seen as a backreference to the last matched *CondPattern*, and there isn't any, so `%2` would otherwise becomes an empty string!

Without the `NE` (`noescape`) flag, mod_rewrite will automatically encode the substitution URL, which is actually what we want in this instance: `%26` gets encoded as `%2526`. (Which, when decoded, is seen as a *literal* `%26`.)

---

Alternatively, you could use the `NE` flag (that @danlefree mentions) and then *manually* encode the substitution:

```
RewriteRule (.*)&(.*) /$1\%2526$2 [R,L,NE]
```

However, this will have issues if there are other %-encoded characters in the URL (unless you match a literal "something" and "else"), as they won't be encoded in the response.

---

Another alternative is to capture the *encoded* URL from `THE_REQUEST` server variable (which contains the URL as it appears on the initial request) and simply pass this through to the *substitution* which then doubly encodes the target URL (in the absence of the `NE` flag):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.*\%26.*)\s
RewriteRule & %1 [R,L]
```

The check for `%26` in the condition is required in case an unencoded "&" is sent in the request (to prevent a redirect loop). The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `&` matches both `&` and `%26` in the requested URL-path (because the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is first URL-decoded).

A caveat with this approach is that if there are any other %-encoded characters in the requested URL then they will also be doubly encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem where the the '&' was incorrectly rewritten by the mod_rewrite. The B flag solved it:

> **B (escape backreferences)** The [B] flag instructs RewriteRule to escape
>   non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation.

It allowed me to serve the files containing '&' within their name, eg [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)

Comment: The `B` flag is specific to _backreferences_, so whether this is relevant to the current question is very much dependent on the directive/method used.